# SQL with group by and having clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table A

```
ID   SALN  INDICATOR
  1    100    A
  2    100    B
  3    200    A
  4    200    C
  5    100    c
  6    300    B
  7    200    D
```

I need to pull SALN from table A  after grouping by SALN and that group having indicator  A,B ,C only

```
SALN
100
```

Please let me know the SQL for this

Answer (score 1):

```
select saln
from A
where indicator in('A','B','C')
group by saln
having sum(indicator) = 100
```

Comment: Why  did you include  sum(indicator) = 100

Comment: Because your out put display to 100 and also specify need to 'having'.

Answer (score 0):

```
select saln
from your_table
group by saln
having sum(indicator not in ('A','B','C')) = 0
```

If you additionally need to check if A, B and C are present for a `SALN` then add

```
and sum(indicator  = 'A') > 0
and sum(indicator  = 'B') > 0
and sum(indicator  = 'C') > 0
```

to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the three values, then you can do:

```
select saln
from A
where indicator in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by saln
having count(*) = 3;
```

If there can be duplicates, then use:

```
having count(distinct indicator) = 3
```

If you want A, B, and C and no other values, then one way is:

```
select saln
from A
group by saln
having count(distinct case when indicator in ('A', 'B', 'C') then indicator end) = 3;
```

Comment: It has retrieved all SALN as one of inidcator related to each of those saln   has A or B orC in it .what i need is any saln related all inicator A and B and C  atleast once

Comment: @shrikanth . . . Are you sure you have a `having` clause?  (Note:  The second code should be *having* and not *where* -- which I originally had.)

Comment: yes. i tried first one as well as second one now. No luck

Comment: @shrikanth . . . It works in SQL Fiddle . . . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b030d/1.

Comment: yes  it works fine in fiddle but not in my system. When i fired same query in  my system it fetched few saln .unfortunately those saln are not linked with all indicator. thank you

Comment: @shrikanth . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with a more reasonable sample of data, and a SQL Fiddle that illustrates your problem.  This and other answers seems to address this particular question.  If you change the question here, it could attract downvotes to the existing answers.